# Labeling in timeseries data in matlab?

Tags: matlab, sorting, label, time-series

i had an array **distarray[] of 35*1** which results from the distance computation of x time series(of a sample) of one user with the x time series of 35 instances. In the distarray[], the first 7 values results from the camparison with **UserA**, next 8 values in the sequence results from comparison with **UserB**, next 10 belongs to **UserC** & the last 10 belongs to **UserD** (7+8+10+10=35).

i want to apply some classifier on these results.prior to this, i want to **label the values** in a way that values that results from the comparison with one user have one label(e.g. in this case, since first 7 computations are of UserA will be labeled as '**UA**', Similarly next 8 values will be labeled as '**UB**', next 10 will be labeled as '**UC**' and the last 10 will be labeled as '**UD**').
In the end, if my distarray[] have values like (distarray = [120,42,25,50,95,47,32,.....252]), if apply some **sort function** on this list, i want the labels also be sorted accordingly.

my code upto distance computation is:

```
 QueryFileDir = 'dirpath';  
 QueryFile = dir( fullfile(QueryFileDir,'QueryFileName') );   
 QueryFile = {QueryFile.name};                    
 TrainingSampleDir= 'dirpath';   
 TrainingFiles = dir( fullfile(TrainingSampleDir,'*.SomeFileExtension') );   
 TrainingFiles = {TrainingFiles.name};                      
 distarray = [];
 resultingdist = [];
   for i=1:length(QueryFile)
     queryfilename = fullfile(QueryFileDir,QueryFile{i}); 
     queryfile = dlmread(queryfilename, '', 2,0);
     xtimeseriesq=queryfile(:,1);        %assigning x timeseries of query sample to c1
       for j=i+1:length(TrainingFiles)
        trainfilenames = fullfile(TrainingSampleDir,TrainingFiles{j});    
        trainfiles = dlmread(trainfilenames, '', 2,0); 
        xtimeseriest=trainfiles(:,1);%assigning x timeseries of training samples to d1 
        resultingdist = dtw(xtimeseriesq,xtimeseriest); % distance computation using x-timeseries of query sample with all training samples                   
        distarray = [distarray; resultingdist]; %resultant distance array                           
       end
    end
```